# Method Invoke() inside click event doesnt change controls values in Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a click Event that inside calls a previously set Action session variable. The problem is that the changes done in the click event shows fine in the page but the changes done inside the Action method called in the invoke doesn't get shown in the page...
Debugging it seems like the Invoked method is in another context/viewstate for the page controls.

Simplified code example:

```
public static Action OKFunction {
    get => (Action) HttpContext.Current.Session["OKFunction"];
    set => HttpContext.Current.Session["OKFunction"] = value;
}

protected void FunctionPrepareCall() {
    //in the long version we prepare a javascript dialog with _doPostback and set the desired target function depending on various conditions, here we show only the problematic part, setting the target function
    OKFunction = DialogDeleteItemAcepted;
}

protected void ConfirmationDialogOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    lbMsg.Text = "TestConfirmDialog"; //this value is what it is shown after the page refreshes
    OKFunction ? .Invoke(); //calling the target function if its assigned
    string currentMsgValue = lbMsg.Text; //right here in debug the value of lbMsg.Text is the one we assigned in this method "TestConfirmDialog";
}

public void DialogDeleteItemAcepted() {
    //right here in debug the value of lbMsg.Text appears empty, like it would be in another thread context/viewstate
    lbMsg.Text = "TestDialogDeleteItemAcepted"; //in the real case the message text would depend on the result of the delete item operation for example
    //right here in debug the value of lbMsg.Text is the one we assigned "TestDialogDeleteItemAcepted";
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that storing an `Action` or any other kind of delegate into the session works at all. (And note that it almost certainly will fail if you need to use more robust session storage that has to serialize the session). I'd be looking to simplify your use of session - storing e.g. an enum value that indicates which method to dispatch to.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the suggestion, in theory is a variable type like any other so the usage of session shouldn't give problems. In this case we wanted to use an Action instead of an enum with a fixed list of cases because this way we can implement it in a function library that can be reused easily in any other web project....

Comment: Are you setting the value during one page lifecycle and then trying to use it in a different cycle? Because the delegate will be bound to the specific `Page` instance that was processing the request in which it was created.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever effectively i set the Action value in one page lifecycle and using it in the next postback, as i said in the question i suspected the Action method was in another context...
Then if i pass in some way the current context to the method as an argument and set it it could work?

Something like:
OKFunction?.Invoke(this); or OKFunction?.Invoke(currentcontext);
And then:
public void DialogDeleteItemAcepted(xContext context){ this.Context= context; lbMsg.Text="TestDialogDeleteItemAcepted";}

Comment: If all of these are methods within the same class there may be a way to tweak the `Action`s so that they always refer to the "current" instance. (`OKFunction` would need to become an instance method). Would that work for your use case?

Comment: The OkFunction in this case is already an instance method of the current page class if that is what you mean...what would be the modification? (you could add it as an answer in case it works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a console application that demonstrates a similar issue:

```
using System;

namespace PlayAreaCSCon
{
  internal class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var s = new Session();
      var c1 = new Page(1, s);
      c1.SetAction();
      c1 = null;
      var c2 = new Page(2, s);
      c2.InvokeAction();
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  public class Session
  {
    public object Thingy;
  }

  public class Page
  {
    int _id;
    Session _session;
    public Page(int id, Session session)
    {
      _id = id;
      _session = session;
    }

    public Action OKFunction
    {
      get { return (Action)_session.Thingy; }
      set { _session.Thingy = value; }
    }
    public void SetAction()
    {
      OKFunction = DelegatedMethod;
    }

    public void DelegatedMethod()
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Delegated method called on page {_id}");
    }

    public void InvokeAction()
    {
      OKFunction.Invoke();
    }
  }
}
```

Run this and it prints "Delegated method called on page 1", even though, of course, we accessed it through page "2".

So, if we change the getter of `OKFunction` to:

```
public Action OKFunction
{
  get { return (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this, 
                         ((Action)_session.Thingy).Method); }
  set { _session.Thingy = value; }
}
```

And now we get the output as "Delegated method called on page 2". You should be able to apply a similar transformation in your `OKFunction` getter to return a new `Action` that targets the current page. `OKFunction` has to become an instance method (non-`static`) so that it can access the `this` member.

This will be broken if whatever was passed to the setter of `OKFunction` wasn't a delegate to an instance method or was bound to an instance of some other class. You may wish to apply further validation within the setter and throw an `ArgumentException` of some kind if what's being set won't work.

Comment: Great, your solution worked, the key was the line:
get { return (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this, 
                         ((Action)_session.Thingy).Method); }